# how to set underline in a sentence by button sequence?

Tags: android, textview, underline, android-spannable

I cannot get the method for this but how can I set/modified a String in a sentence with an underline in a **textview**? i wanted like this, when i click the button the underline will move to the next string and click again the underline will move again.
I really don't know what type of code or what kind of method is using for like this or what ever call for this.

```
example 1: _the_ red fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

if the button is click then the underline should be in "the".

```
example 2: the _red_ fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

if the button is click again then the underline should be in "red".

and so on.

I am new in this type of method i cannot search about this kind of code. Please help me for this kind of code Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

how can i set a underline code for like this:

```
The _***_ *** ***** **** *** **** ***.
```

and when i click again the button the under move again like this:

```
The *** _***_ ***** **** *** **** ***.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UnderlineSpan` Try this

```
    public CharSequence formatText(String base, String highlight) {
        int start = base.indexOf(highlight);
        if (start >= 0) {
            SpannableString span = new SpannableString(base);
            span.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), start, start + highlight.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            return span;
        }
        return base;
    }
```

When you click you should pass base string and highlight string you want

```
textView.setText(formatText("the red fox jumps over the lazy dog.", "the"));
```

Comment: can this be ok in a button sequence? like in my sample above? i like to try this by using programmatically not by manual putting what should be displayed.

Comment: You should implement inside click, it should be call with new highlight value, I mean next word you want

Comment: i have a little short problem for the code the problem is what if my sentence would like this: The *** *** ***** **** *** ***. the code you given is perfectly fit in a sentence thank you by the way. is there any help for like this?